# How to open a folder by browsing and display the name of the selected item in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to do brwosing and display the selected file name in a textview.How can I do this in Xamarin android.

please help me..

```
    private void UploadBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Uploadintent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        _Uploadintent.SetType("file/*");
        _Uploadintent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(_Uploadintent, "Select Picture"), 1);

    }
```

[image]

I want to display the file name like  above image

Comment: By `I want to do brwosing` and `_Uploadintent.SetType("image/*");`, do you want to make a image selector? Or file browser?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT File Browser

Comment: But from your code, it like you want to open your gallery and get a picture? If you want to make a File Browser, what is your problem?

Comment: Actually I want the name of the selected file..

Comment: Yes, but your question is so widely, you can use a `listview` to show the files, and add the click event on every item, and then show their name which is contained in data. Is it right?

Comment: My browse button is contained in a table layout and  after selecting the file, the file name is bind into a textview. This is actually I want ,how can I do this..

Comment: Please show your codes to make your question clear. I will test it, and provide a demo on github for you. Is Xamarin.Android project? Do you want to use bind like Xamarin.Forms({bind ...})?

Comment: Hi, I will make a demo for you tomorrow, please update your question with the related codes, thanks!

Comment: It's xamarin.android project.

Comment: Hi, I have made a demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/FileBorwer), you can try it, and leave me a comment. If there is something worng, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Yes It's working in Activity,  and I adding the code into my fragment.Thanks for your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169209/discussion-between-aswathy-and-joe-lv-msft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like comment, I have made a demo [here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/FileBorwer).

Use `*/*` to open file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.SetType("*/*");
intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

After get the uri, you can use the `getRealPathFromURI` method and `getPath` method to get the file's paths and show them.

Comment: Hi, @Aswathy. In fragment, you need use get context by `Activity` property. And override `OnActivityResult` method in `MainActivity`, if you want update your ui, you can use interface to achieve it. Can you tell me  what problem are you facing with?

Comment: Hi, @Aswathy, I have updated my [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/FileBorwer) with fragment. What is the error? Please edit your question with the error.

Comment: I also updated my solution with your code, and now I got the correct solution.Actually the error is a conflict between the system.uri namespace and Android.net.uri namespace.It's a mistake from my side, sorry for that. Could you please tell how to bind the path name into a textview in the fragment.I am a fresher in xamarin...

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://mallibone.com/post/xamarinandroid-and-mvvm-light-bindings). In Xamarin.Forms, we usually use MVVM Cross to bind, but on Android, maybe [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) will give you some help.